# Import and evaluate a node_modules script globally (Browser) in a vue project (created with vue-cli)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, global-variables, webpack-4, vue-cli-3

I'm having a vue project (v2.6, + vuex, vue-router, webpack), created by vue-cli (v3.11) - https://gitlab.com/Tech4Comp/eas.lit-ui/tree/a71b84b732b408d8b292918bc8e6db9f0a1133e6

I'm trying to include a third party library (inside the file `src/components/oidcButton.vue`) - `"openidconnect-signin": "git://github.com/rwth-acis/openidconnect-signin.git#global-oidc"` - which expects some global variables to be available in the browser (not just as of the vue context). One of these is "UserManager", which should be made available by "oidc-client" - `/node_modules/oidc-client/lib/oidc-client.js`, which is a dependency of `openidconnect-signin`.

Try to clone the repo (keep attention to the branch and commit I've mentioned), install dependencies and execute the project by `npm run serve` and you'll notice the problem in the browser console.

What I actually want to do is:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script src="/node_modules/oidc-client/lib/oidc-client.js"></script>
  </head
  ...
</html>
```

as it is described in https://github.com/rwth-acis/openidconnect-signin/blob/global-oidc/README.md .

Unfortunately `vue-cli-service serve` won't publish the node_modules directory (which makes totally sense). So I tried to find a way to accomplish the task with vue/vue-head/some webpack tipps (script-loader, shimming, others I don't remember) and some more libraries. E.g. by importing the file as it is in the main.js, adding it as a script tag to the App.vue, etc.. Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with webpack and vue is already doing a lot of webpack stuff I don't want to interfere with. I ended up beeing frustated and copying the file from the node_modules folder to the public folder (which is served as it is). But this can't be the solution....

What's the correct way to import & evaluate a file globally in the browser without copying it to the public folder?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't rely on your dependencies' dependencies without specifying them as your own. If you need to access `oidc-client/lib/oidc-client.js`, then specify `oidc-client` as a dependency. Just assuming the presence of these libraries in your node_modules forever and always, just because they were a nested dependecy once is a road to madness and broken code.

You were on the right track with `import`ing the library in your main.js file. The only sensible way to ensure you have access to things in the Webpack world is by importing them into it. Adding libraries via `<script>` tags dont always play well with Webpack and your mileage may vary.

If the library expects to be available globally, shimming is definitely the way to go. Try something like this:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      oidc_client: 'oidc-client',
    }),
  ],
};
```

then later

```
oidc_client.UserManager
```

and see where that gets you.

Comment: Commented the initial answer, that later has been rewritten: Many thanks for your suggestion. I've linked to the specific commit on Gitlab which includes the mentioned file and also the import in package.json. I've also already implemented it as you suggested it within the linked commit. See https://gitlab.com/Tech4Comp/eas.lit-ui/blob/a71b84b732b408d8b292918bc8e6db9f0a1133e6/src/components/oidcButton.vue
I've tried to move the import to the App.vue, but I'm getting the same ReferenceError described in my initial question.

Comment: Interesting. I'll pull your changes and have a look!

Comment: Actually the library from Github is expecting the global variable, see https://github.com/rwth-acis/openidconnect-signin/blob/e6d0d367cd2092263884c1f2b9b862318ed0747b/openidconnect-signin.js#L160 and the corresponding issue I've opened https://github.com/rwth-acis/openidconnect-signin/issues/18

Comment: That would explain a lot, I came to the same conclusion poking around. They aren't importing or defining UserManager anywhere before using it. Don't think it's anything you're doing wrong at all, looks like it's their issue. Apologies if I came across as patronising. Best of luck with this.

Comment: Oh no, that's totally fine. I've struggeled describing the problem in a nutshell, with all it's complexity and things I've tried myself. Many thanks for looking into it and posting an alternative way!